# File get contens Str_replace external site not working

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hello im trying to get the information from 
http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/05/c/c00050.htm

And want to replace `<b>1</b>` with `<b>1e uur</b>`
But when i tried this code it doesnt work

```
<?php 
$Week = $_GET['Week'];

$R = file_get_contents('http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/'.$Week.'/c/c00050.htm');
$R = str_replace("<b>1</b>","<b>1e uur</b>", $R);

echo $R;
?>
```

When i go to **www.mywebsite.com/Page.php?Week=05** it shows the page but it didnt replace the bold :'(

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Is it `str_replace` or `file_get_contents` that is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<?php 
$Week = $_GET['Week'];

$R = file_get_contents('http://rooster.farelcollege.nl/'.$Week.'/c/c00050.htm');
$R = str_replace("<B>1</B>","<b>1e uur</b>", $R);

echo $R;
?>
```

The html tags are capitalized and str_replace is case sensitive.

Alternatively you can also use str_ireplace which is case insensitive.